# In Unity, how can i instantiate 4 images that are clickable?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Id like to make a language learning game but im trying to instantiate images that are clickable and have 4 instantiate where one is correct and when all 4 are instantiated an audio clip plays that is associated with one of the images.

Comment: Should the audio clip play when you instantiated the images? Or should it play when you clicked the correct image?

Comment: I want the audio clip to play when all 4 images appear on screen and then i have to choose the correct image associated with the audio.

Comment: Is it always the same 4 images or can it be 5 or 3 sometimes?

Comment: Well its not the same 4 images. It would pick 4 from maybe 100 or more images and display 4 of them and have an audio clip associated with one of them. Then if you pick the right one you get a point or something and if you get it wrong you lose a life. And then 4 new images from the 100 would appear with a new audio clip

Comment: I also want to make like a 3 second time limit so if they dont choose anything they lose a life.

Answer (score 0):

First I would make a Class to manage that each Image has an associated AudioClip.

```
class Answers{
    AudioClip clip;
    Sprite img;
}
```

Then you can create as many Answers as you choose (here 1 as an example)

```
AudioClip clip1; // define in inspector
Answers[] answers = {Resources.Load <Sprite>("name_of_the_sprite"), clip1}; // Sprite with the name will be loaded in runtime
```

Instead of instantiating new Images you should now just be able to edit the same ones. Because only the Image on the objects and the audio clip needs to change.

**To manage that, we write a Function:**

```
// Defining Images that we want to change
public Image img1;
public Image img2;
public Image img3;
public Image img4;

// Call it each time you want to change the Answers
public void ChangeImages()
{
     // Selecting 4 Random Images
     Answers a1 = answers[answers.RandomRange(0, answers.Count)];
     Answers a2 = answers[answers.RandomRange(0, answers.Count)];
     Answers a3 = answers[answers.RandomRange(0, answers.Count)];
     Answers a4 = answers[answers.RandomRange(0, answers.Count)];

     // Change Sprite of the Images
     img1.sprite = a1.img;
     img2.sprite = a2.img;
     img3.sprite = a3.img;
     img4.sprite = a4.img;
     
     // To make that random just make a switch statement
     int randomnumber = Random.Range(1, 5)

     // Correct Solution
     int correctImage = 0;         

     // Play your audioclip, for which every Image you want to be correct
     switch (randomnumber)
     {
         case 1:
             PlayAudioClip(a1.clip);
             correctImage = 1;
             break;
         case 2:
             PlayAudioClip(a2.clip);
             correctImage = 2;
             break;
         case 3:
             PlayAudioClip(a3.clip);
             correctImage = 3;
             break;
         case 4:
             PlayAudioClip(a4.clip);
             correctImage = 4;
             break;
     }
}
```

If the player now clicks on an Image you can check if it was the correct one with the correct Image number and depending on that let the player continue or end the game.

Comment: Im not following completely. Would i need to make an array for the images? How do they get displayed on the screen? What do you mean by call it each time? Is the audio clip associated with one of the images? Are they clickable like buttons?

Comment: As far as i understood it. You want 4 images that you change each "turn". At the start of each "turn" each image get's 4 "random" pictures and then a audio clip starts that is equal to one of the images. Then when you click on it in 3 seconds the next "turn" starts.

Comment: Yes essentially. So the gameobjects are not UI?

Comment: They are UI, you can just make an Image that also has a Button Object on it so it's clickable

Comment: Ok so i would make 4 image UI’s with a button component and put the script on the main camera? Does it matter where the script goes? If i make prefabs for the images where would it choose the images from? Where would the Random.Range() go?

Comment: I'm editing my answer rn and I would put script onto a Game Manager Object so it's more clear. But you could put it onto anything as longs as everything is in the same script or you can call them from everywhere.